# Constructor error in C++

Tags: c++

I just started to learn cpp. I created a class with 2 constructors.
When I run this command on ubuntu:  `g++ -Wall -g  main.cpp  car.cpp -o a`
I'm getting an error massage:

```
> "In file included from main.cpp:2:0: car.h:10:15: 
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token  car(string,string,int);

In file included from car.cpp:1:0: car.h:10:15: 
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token car(string,string,int);

car.cpp:10:9: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token  car::car(string brand, string color, int cost){  "
```

I don't understand why Im getting this error message, what is wrong with my code? 
Please help me.

This is my code:

This is an h file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#pragma once

class car{

    public:
    car();
    car(string,string,int);
    int get_cost();
    std::string get_brand();
    std::string get_color();

    private:
    std::string newbrand;
    std::string newcolor;
    int newcost;

};
```

This is car.cpp file:

```
#include "car.h"

car::car(){
    this->newcost=0;
    this->newbrand="No Brand";
    this->newcolor="No color"; 
}

car::car(string brand, string color, int cost){
   newbrand=brand;
   newcolor=color;
   newcost=cost; 
}

int car:: get_cost(){
    return newcost;
}


std::string car:: get_brand(){
    return newbrand;
}

std::string car:: get_color(){
    return newcolor;
}
```

This is my main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "car.h"

int main(){
     car c;
     std::cout <<c.get_brand()<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `string`? Do you mean `std::string`?

Comment: I include it in the h  file, where i worte the class.

Comment: If you're learning C++, you might be interested in our list of [good C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

string is in namespace std, so you have to use std::string.

And **#pragma once** must be in the first line!

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class car{

    public:
    car();
    car(std::string, std::string, int);
    int get_cost();
    std::string get_brand();
    std::string get_color();

    private:
    std::string newbrand;
    std::string newcolor;
    int newcost;

};
```